# How to set alsa playback buffer size?

Tags: c, alsa, buildroot

My application cannot set alsa playback buffer size in embedded system created with buildroot. But under Ubuntu desktop same application can set buffer size ok.

```
snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;
snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);
snd_pcm_hw_params_any(m_DeviceHandle, params);

err  = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(m_DeviceHandle, params, SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED);
if(err<0) printf("fail snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access()\n");

snd_pcm_format_t f = SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE;
err =  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(m_DeviceHandle, params, f);
if(err<0) printf("fail snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format()\n");

err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(m_DeviceHandle, params, nChanels);
if(err<0) printf("fail snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels()\n");

unsigned int Freq = 22050;
err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(m_DeviceHandle, params, &Freq, &dir);
if(err<0) printf("fail snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near()\n");

snd_pcm_uframes_t frames = Freq / 100;
err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near(m_DeviceHandle, params, &frames, &dir);
if(err<0) printf("fail snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near()\n");

snd_pcm_uframes_t buf_size = 128*1024;
err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_size_near(m_DeviceHandle, params, &buf_size );
if(err<0) printf("fail snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_size_near()\n");

printf("Actual Audio Freq %d Period %d bufsize %d\n",Freq, frames,buf_size);
```

Last printf under Ubuntu desktop shows 
`Actual Audio Freq 22050 Period 220 bufsize 131120`
but in my embedded system created with buildroot
`Actual Audio Freq 22050 Period 470 bufsize 7526`

So definitely ALSA works differently under my Ubuntu and my embedded system.
How can I increase alsa play buffer size if snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_size_near() does not work?
Also function snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near() should set period to 220 (and it does under x64-86 Ubuntu) but under my embedded system which is also x86 buildroot it is 470.

I am building embedded system with buildroot and I choose kernel options myself. Well, I have copied all sound related kernel options from my Ubuntu .config to buildroot kernel config (and then rebuild Lunux kernel and buildroot image). But this does not help anyhow. Behave is exactly same wrong - cannot set buffer size.

I was searching any alsa.conf option which allows to set application play buffer size but I do not see any option neither in /etc/asound.conf nor in /usr/share/alsa/*.conf even ~/asoundrc.conf

Strange difference which I see is

```
$ cat /proc/asound/card0/pcm0p/sub0/prealloc_max
128
```

on Ubuntu
but on my embedded system

```
$ cat /proc/asound/card0/pcm0p/sub0/prealloc_max
32768
```

But I cannot set somehow this limit it is not changable.

I can modify other file 
/proc/asound/card0/pcm0p/sub0/prealloc

```
$echo "128" > /proc/asound/card0/pcm0p/sub0/prealloc
```

but any number which I write can increase playbuffer shown in application printf only up to 7526
Or if I do

```
$echo "64" > /proc/asound/card0/pcm0p/sub0/prealloc
```

then application printf says my buffer size is 3763:

`Actual Audio Freq 22050 Period 470 bufsize 3763`

How play buffer size can be increased up to 64K samples or 120K samples?
On Ubuntu desktop it is easy but what is wrong with my embedded x86 system created under buildroot?

Comment: Are you using `dmix`? Anyway, hardware parameters depend on the capabilities of the hardware.

Comment: How can I check using I dmix or not?

Comment: I am using just ALSA API and what is behind - I do not know.

Comment: Try `aplay -v something.wav`.